# Print XPS with PrintTicket, OutputColor PagesPerSheet not working

Tags: windows, printing, xps

I have a .xps file generated from build-in Microsoft xps writer printer, I want to print this to a real printer but with modified attributes such as: duplex, grayscale, n-up etc.

I followed examples from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771525.aspx) and I can print .xps fine, but the problem is I can only set few attributes of the job. By setting PrintTicket with PrintQueue, job printed correctly with modified copies and duplex settings, but will not convert to grayscale or honor any n-up settings.

It seems I am not alone, from [this form](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsxps/thread/eb1aab0d-f015-479e-9fe7-bfb848a4d58b) , by using event handler of WritingPrintTicketRequired, XPS files PrintTicket has been successfully changed with grayscale, n-up settings, but by using PrintQueue.AddJob() call will not print them in grayscale or n-up setting.

However, if I use [PrintDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.aspx) and manually select attributes then it would print as expected. If I try to set PrintQueue and PrintTicket property in PrintDialog then it won't honor some of the attributes.

My goal is is programmatically print xps file with attributes. The question is how can I make PrintQueue fully honor PrintTicket?

FYI: the xps file was generated as color and I can see color images in .xps package.

EDIT: it turns out is the printer driver somehow does not honor print settings,even printer capabilities show it support monochrome, veryfied by changing to another driver.  However, specify grayscale in print ticket is different than selecting grayscale in print dialog UI: grayscale in print ticket would output monochrome image and in spool file, it is specified to render as colour but the image it self is converted. While the later would generating a more realistic grayscale image.

Comment: You are correct. The printer driver may not honor the settings in the Print Ticket. The ideal way may be for you to change the XPS content that you send to the printer driver. Is your application intended for testing various XPS files with PT attributes?

Comment: I have tried change PT in XPS file but it is same result. It seems it is only possible by change actual content of XPS file, by converting to grayscale, merge multiple pages into one (n-up). Is there any lib I can use instead write my own raw xps parser + image processor?

Comment: What is your specific req? - Is your application intended for testing various XPS files with PT attributes?

Comment: @Yuan Did you ever get a solution for your question? I am also trying to print an XPS with n-up setting, but the printer ignores it. It seems like the printer driver does not support changing it from DEVMODE structure, but only in private printer data. You managed to merge n page on a single one in XPS?

Comment: @Scoregraphic No, I haven't. It seems there is no way around it apart from modifing print ticket's private part ( vendor specific), different vendor would use different format. One way to do it is do n-up manually, i.e. scale different pages and put them on one page.